# Low FPS on streaming OpenCV with gstreamer to RTSP

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, raspberry-pi-zero

I got the following code:

```
import cv2
import gi

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstRtspServer', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GstRtspServer, GObject, GLib


class SensorFactory(GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory):
def __init__(self, **properties):
    super(SensorFactory, self).__init__(**properties)
    self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    print("Start")
    self.number_frames = 0
    self.fps = 30
    self.duration = 1 / self.fps * Gst.SECOND  # duration of a frame in nanoseconds
    self.launch_string = 'appsrc name=source is-live=true block=true format=GST_FORMAT_TIME ' \
                         'caps=video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ' \
                         '! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ' \
                         '! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency ' \
                         '! rtph264pay config-interval=1 name=pay0 pt=96'

def on_need_data(self, src, lenght):
    if self.cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        if ret:
            data = frame.tobytes()
            buf = Gst.Buffer.new_allocate(None, len(data), None)
            buf.fill(0, data)
            buf.duration = self.duration
            timestamp = self.number_frames * self.duration
            buf.pts = buf.dts = int(timestamp)
            buf.offset = timestamp
            self.number_frames += 1
            retval = src.emit('push-buffer', buf)
            print('pushed buffer, frame {}, duration {} ns, durations {} s'.format(self.number_frames,
                                                                                       self.duration,
                                                                                               self.duration / Gst.SECOND))
            if retval != Gst.FlowReturn.OK:
                print(retval)

def do_create_element(self, url):
    return Gst.parse_launch(self.launch_string)

def do_configure(self, rtsp_media):
    self.number_frames = 0
    appsrc = rtsp_media.get_element().get_child_by_name('source')
    appsrc.connect('need-data', self.on_need_data)


class GstServer(GstRtspServer.RTSPServer):
def __init__(self, **properties):
    super(GstServer, self).__init__(**properties)
    self.factory = SensorFactory()
    self.factory.set_shared(True)
    self.get_mount_points().add_factory("/cam1", self.factory)
    self.attach(None)


#GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)

server = GstServer()


loop = GLib.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

This streams my Camera from my Raspberry Pi Zero and I can get the stream inside VLC. The only problem is the Framerate it's maybe 1 FPS. How could I improve the FPS? The main goal after this would be to access the RTSP stream inside Homebridge so I can display it inside the Homekit app.

**Edit:**

I just checked my CPU usage, it's between 90% and 100%. Could that be the problem?

Comment: yes, that sounds like a problem.

Comment: You are doing all these pixel operations and video encoding on the CPU. The Raspi Zero's CPU is way too weak for that.

Comment: H264 encodingis expensive. Try to find out whether there is hardware acceleration available for raspberry pi (e.g. special chip, gpu, neon)

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/29548/46716

Comment: Thanks, gonna try it. Else I'm gonna try to just stream the RP0 cam without anything special and do everything OpenCV related on my RP3 and then stream it again with gstreamer.

Comment: streaming raw images will likely not work well because of needed bandwidth. For 640 x 480 with 30 fps you would need at least 222 Mbit/s without regarding any packet overhead and throughput limitations.

Comment: I just tried the following (to just stream the video): raspivid -o - -t 0 -rot 180 -w 1920 -h 1080 -fps 30 -b 2000000 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/stream}' :demux=h264

This kinda works, Quality and FPS are great but the delay is a bit annoying (about 3-5 Seconds)